# How do I use the JDK compiler with Dr Java instead of the Eclipse compiler?

Tags: java, java-6, drjava

My school forces us to use Dr Java and I'm having trouble getting it to use the JDK compiler instead of the Eclipse compiler.

Comment: According to the FAQ, the built-in compiler of DrJava is the Eclipse compiler: http://drjava.org/docs/user/ch06s03.html

Comment: What code are you writing that needs a specific compiler?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm making a game and I have load images onto the screen, I think the Eclipse compiler has some sort of an error making this impossible. + we're supposed to be using the JDK compiler

Comment: Images aren't compiled, they are just copied... Please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried to load files with and any error you're getting if that's your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall JRE so that it will update JAVA_HOME, Path. Alternately, update [JAVA_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html), [Path](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) manually in advanced system settings (if using windows)

Then configure [Dr Java](http://drjava.org/docs/user/apa.html) to use the newly installed JDK

Comment: "Then configure Dr Java to use the newly installed JDK", can you please explain that part?